# Why are magnetic fields represented as revolving around the direction of motion?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I was watching a video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoVW7CRR5JY) about how electric and magnetic fields are related, and I understand that electric and magnetic fields are the same and the only different thing is the perspective of observing.

But one thing during the video that made me wonder was the way a magnetic field is described(image below, it's at 8m 21s of the video). [image]

My question is "By switching the perspective of observing the phenomenon, how does the shape of the electric field transform into the shape of a magnetic field(image above)?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "shape" isn't directly transforming. Instead, a changing electric field creates a magnetic field with a specific orientation and vice versa.
Imagine a spinning charged sphere. The electric field from the stationary charge itself might be radial (outward from the sphere). But due to the spinning motion (which is a form of changing electric field), a magnetic field would also be generated, following a circular pattern around the sphere's axis.

Answer (score 0):

On way to do this problem is to define the particles charge and current density (moving up the $z$-axis...always use the $z$-axis).

$$ \vec j(\vec r, t) = qr\delta(r - vt)\delta(\theta)\delta(\phi)\hat r$$

and plug it into Jefimenko's equation, which will not be fun, but will show the correct field shapes as a function of time. This method has the benefit of showing your that changing fields do not create complementary fields; rather, all fields at an point/time are the results of charges, currents and their derivatives on the past light cone.

The easier way is to start with a charge at rest:

$$ \vec E = k\frac{q \hat r}{r^2} $$
$$ \vec B = 0 $$

and then Lorentz transform to a frame moving in the $-z$-direction (see: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_26.html, with $B=0$)

$$ E'_{\parallel} = E_{\parallel}$$

$$ E'_{\perp} = \frac 1 {\gamma} E_{\perp}$$

so that obviously "stretches" the electric field in the xy-plane.

Meanwhile, the only magnetic term is:

$$ B'_{\perp} = \frac{kq}{r^2}\frac{\hat z \times \hat r}{\gamma c^2}$$

so $\hat z \times \hat r$ lies in the xy-plane, and that $1/r^2$ gives the bulge in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Electric and magnetic fields are not the same. For example, one exerts a force on a non-moving particle, the other does not.

If you have a field which is purely electric in some inertial reference frame, then there are other frames in which it takes the form of a combination of electric and magnetic.

Similarly, if a field is purely magnetic in some inertial reference frame, then there are other frames in which it takes the form of a combination of electric and magnetic.

However a field cannot be purely electric in one frame and purely magnetic in another. One way to derive this is to first show that the combination $E^2 - c^2 B^2$ takes the same value in all frames.

When a particle is moving and there is a magnetic field, the force on it has a contribution from the magnetic field, equal to $q {\bf v} \times {\bf B}$. If you consider the situation in the rest frame of the particle, it has no velocity but there is still a force. The force is owing to the electric field in the new frame.

The overall lesson, then, is that magnetic and electric fields are related but they are not the same. The technically accurate way to state the relationship is to say that they are two parts of a single field called a tensor field.